# JavaScript switch statement confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
getDateRange = function () {
        date = new Date();
        var test;
        selectedOption = $('#daterange').change().val()
        console.log(selectedOption) // reusult 0
        switch (selectedOption) {
            case 0:
                test = '/' + date.getFullYear() + '-' + 0 + date.getMonth() + '-' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear() + '-' + 0 + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate()
                break
        }
        return test
    }
    console.log($('#daterange').change().val()) // result 0
    console.log(getDateRange()) // result "undefined". Why?
```

Why is the result of the switch statement always `undefined`?

Comment: why you need a `switch` if you have only 1 case? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your case statement to `case '0'` since `val()` returns a string.

Also: If you are not doing any other things after your switch statement except returning your test variable, you could also just return your value and get rid of `var test`.

```js
getDateRange = function() {
  date = new Date();
  selectedOption = $('#daterange').change().val();
  switch (selectedOption) {
    case '0':
      return '/' + date.getFullYear() + '-' + 0 + date.getMonth() + '-' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear() + '-' + 0 + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate();
  }
}
console.log(getDateRange());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="daterange" value="0" />
```

Comment: Or `case '0':` Why waste time parsing?

Comment: As an aside, if you ever want to quickly cast a string to a numeric equivalent you can simply add a plus sign before the string. A.e. +'0' === 0

Answer (score 1):

`$('#daterange').change().val()` returns a string, but in switch you compare with a number.

Also, in the current example, you don't need switch, because you have only one case:

```
getDateRange = function () {
    var selectedOption = $('#daterange').change().val();
    if (selectedOption === '0') {
       return ...
    }
}
```

Comment: why `switch` when you have only 1 case? :(

Comment: @Dekel, isn't that the question for the OP?

Comment: Even if the question was about the switch - you should give a better answer, based on the code that you see

Comment: There will be mor cases as soo I get the one working

Comment: Kudos to @alexmac.

Comment: @zfrisch When I see a code I look at it the way it is. The problem with the OP's code was the comparison, and not the switch/case. If it was my answer I would at least mention the 1 case (and write how that code would look like without the switch/case). We are here to teach/learn, and this is a great example.

Answer (score 0):

I javascript your dataType should be tighly match with your comparision operatot, so compare it with ===

In this case type and data both will match together.

```
getDateRange = function() {
  date = new Date();
  selectedOption = $('#daterange').change().val();
  switch (selectedOption) {
    case '0':
      return '/' + date.getFullYear() + '-' + 0 + date.getMonth() + '-' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear() + '-' + 0 + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate();
  }
}
console.log(getDateRange());
```